# be there for all to see

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> “I feel much better now compared to back in spring training,’’ Sanchez said through an interpreter Wednesday at Yankee Stadium. “Overall, I’ve had more time to practice and work with my new stance. In spring training, my back held me back a little bit and prevented me from going at it the way I wanted to. The past two or three months, I went to the Dominican Republic and worked really hard on it.”
>
> The results will **be there for all to see** soon enough.

[Source](https://nypost.com/2020/07/15/gary-sanchez-cant-wait-to-show-off-new-improved-catching-stance/)

---

What's the meaning and grammatical construction of "**be there for all to see**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very close to literal.  If something *is there for all to see*, then it is somewhere that everyone can see it. It is there, and (or *so*) all may see it. It is in a public place.

When applied to something abstract, like "results", it just means that anyone can know about the results. The results are public.

In this context, the baseball player has been working on his stance. Soon he will be playing baseball matches, and the improvement in his stance will mean that he plays better, and everyone who watches him will know that he is playing better, because he will be playing in public.

Comment: There is no the object of "**see**". What's the reason why?

Comment: @Englishgood **see** doesn't need an explicit object.  "(something) for you to *verb*" means that you can *verb* the thing.

Comment: @stangdon Does "**for all to see**" mean "(in order) **for all to see**"?

Comment: How would you understand "The chips are for all to eat".  It means "Everyone can/may eat the chips".

Comment: @Englishgood Yes, that is essentially correct.  It is there so that all may see it.

Comment: @stangdon I'd like to ask more questions. 1. Does "The results for all to see will be there soon enough." have the same meaning? 2. Is this idiomatic?

Comment: @Englishgood Your new sentence means the same thing, and I think it is grammatically correct, but it is not an idiomatic way to phrase it.